# Custom Date Format with Channel Form + Matrix + Date Fieldtype

Tags: ee2, matrix, safecracker, pixelandtonic, channel-form

We have a channel form setup and it's all working fine.

In the form is a matrix field called "job_timings" and we call on it via `{field:job_timings}`

The matrix has two columns - one a text field and the other a date field. The datepicker works fine in the channel form it's just that is displays dates in the format of `2014-01-23 4:59 PM` to the end user.

In our case we don't need a time and we need the date formatted as dd-mm-yyyy.

Is there any way to control the format of this matrix date field?

Answer (score 2):

I believe any [date field in EE should have the `format` parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html) available.

Correct syntax in this case would be something like `{field:job_timings format="%d-%m-%Y"}`.

Comment: Hi Nick // Doesn't look like that syntax works with Matrix Fields. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while attempting to solve a similar problem; hopefully this will be helpful to others who need the same functionality in the future.

[Event Helper](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/eevent-helper) is a plugin that comes with a field type that allows for a simple date formatting WITHOUT a time stamp that can be used in GRID and MATRIX.

The actual Event Helper extension still needs to be updated for the new EE version (I'm running 2.9.2) or it will create PHP errors, so I recommend installing ONLY the field type.